# Database design for an inventory system in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, controllers

I want to create a basic inventory system using laravel. I have 2 tables. One for purchases and another for sales.
Fields in purchase table: id, product_id,quantity_bought, date_bought.

Fields in sales table: id, product_id, quantity_sold, date_sold

How would I perform validations such that quantity_sold can't be greater than quantity_bought? Also how would I get quantity_remaining and save it in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should add another table `products` which holds the current amount in stock.

Then you can create an Eloquent relation between `products` and `purchases` and `sales`. So the `product_id` column in `purchases` and `sales` point to the products table. For more info see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Then, once you need to add a new sales you can do a transaction in which you check if the current amount in stock for the products is higher than the amount of products sold. And if all is well you update the current amount in stock and create the new entry for the sales table. If any of the checks fail, just rollback the transaction, if all is good, commit it. For more info on transactions see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions

That way the `amount_in_stock` of the `products` table will always have the current amount in stock and your `purchases` and `sales` tables will be your log.

---

Getting back to validation, in this setup you'll need to query the `products` table for the current amount in stock. You can just fetch it from db and compare it with your input for the sales (which you should do  anyway). There's no out of the box Laravel validation rule that can check the value of table x and compare it with a table column somewhere. Of course you can create your own, but I don't really see why you should do that here. In any case, check out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by defining a `totalBoughts($product_id)` in your "Purchase" model and `totalSolds($product_id)` in your "Sales" table and call in your controller by giving product id

> but this is not an efficient way to do so

alternatively you can create relationship between these two with a stock table where u can store current status of the product

> when purchasing the stock incremented and for sale it decrease the amount of products so u cannot manually check the entire table for availability
>   if any product in stock is set to `0` then it can't be sold

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice library for inventory for Laravel. Supports both 4 and 5
https://github.com/stevebauman/inventory

Tables according to the library are as follows

```
+---------------------------------+
|Table Names                      |
+---------------------------------+
| categories                      |
| inventories                     |
| inventory_skus                  |
| inventory_stock_movements       |
| inventory_stocks                |
| inventory_suppliers             |
| inventory_transaction_histories |
| inventory_transactions          |
| locations                       |
| metrics                         |
| migrations                      |
| password_resets                 |
| suppliers                       |
| users                           |
+---------------------------------+
```